# firebase fails to save all data that i m trying to import

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i m trying to to import data from a dict in the firebase and it looks like its loading it but instead of adding the data fields it looks like its just iterating though it cuz i can see all different values change and then it just saves the last one. how do i make it save it all?

```
data=dict(zip(time, counts))

for i,j in data.items():
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'data_storage').document(u'some_data')
    doc_ref.set({
     u'time' : i,
     u'counts' : j
```

Answer (score 3):

All your writes target the same document:

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'data_storage').document(u'some_data')
```

This loop overwrites the `some_data` document again and again. Here's how to create a new document for each data point:

```
for i, j in data.items():
    coll_ref = db.collection(u'data_storage').document(u'some_data').collection(u'data') 
    coll_ref.add({
     u'time': i,
     u'counts': j})
```

Each new document gets an auto-generated ID.

Comment: i wanted that in the 3rd field(child field?) not in the document field. so the first line data database name then in the second column the different tables and in the third the data of the dif tables if i can refer to relational db's . does that make sense?

Comment: I think so, but you can only `add` documents to a collection. That may affect your data model. Updated the answer to show additional hierarchy. Is that closer to what you're trying to do?

Comment: the hierarchy i m trying to achieve is data_storage the name of the db or collection and then have two " tables" called time and counts and then add to each the respective data. does it make sense?

Comment: ok. i did them separately and it finally created an additional field! thank you so much - i am a newbe in the firebase and got lost for a min in the hierarchy of structures!